# Winscp SFTP error:**Server refused public key signature despite accepting key.**

Tags: windows, sftp, openssh

I have installed Openssh on windows 2008 server, I was able to connect to it using public key authentication from my windows client machine, but after few days started getting error like below.
**Server refused public key signature despite accepting key.**

I am using winscp to connect to remote machine.

Comment: Can you connect with any other SFTP/SSH client using the key?

Comment: Anyway, please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.